# Is there a better method for storing data for rooms in a dungeon generator?

Tags: arrays, swift, algorithm, 2d

I'm currently building a dungeon generating algorithm for a game that starts with a 7x7 grid. 49 total spaces. One of the spaces will be a starting room, and another one will be an exit room. The other 47 spaces will be rooms are sized randomly between 5x5 and 11x11 in length and width respectively.

I don't want the rooms to be procedurally generated. I want to handcraft each room. I have a total of 36 possible room sizes, and I want a couple of variations for each size. Currently, a total of 108 (36 x 3 for the variations) unique rooms with unique features.

Currently, I am using a list of 2D arrays each with their own name using a 1 or 0 to represent filled or empty space like so:

[image: Image 1]

My goal is to get the size of the room, and then assign it an array based off of its size and a random number between 1 and 3. But I feel like there is a better way to do this. What would be the best way to go about storing this data? Are 2D arrays a good way to do this?

Comment: Please post real code, not a picture of code.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to generate rooms then you need to store your layout data. But I think the place for this should be in resources rather than source code, easiest way is to create text files and load them.

Comment: Im not even sure how to load information from a text document.

Comment: You can use Scanner and iterate over whole text, but then you should really on first line before all the ones and zeroes add 2 values that represents width and height.

Next step would be CSV file and implementing csv parser.